# mysql check value with null

Tags: mysql, sql, null

In mysql table `real_account_id`'s data type is `int(11)`.
I want to fetch all records with NULL values.

I am using this simple query.

```
SELECT * FROM `customer_payment_options` WHERE real_account_id = NULL
```

But, it's not giving me any results. There are 2 records in database with NULL value.
I also tried with,

```
SELECT * FROM `customer_payment_options` WHERE real_account_id = 'NULL'
```

Why is it like this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NULL` is equal to nothing including `NULL`. That's why you must use [`IS NULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-null):

```
SELECT * FROM `customer_payment_options` WHERE real_account_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any technical reason behind that? Because, comparing with `NULL` is the same thing

Comment: To tell you the truth I am not sure why this is. A maybe good explanation can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16463613/250259).