# Why isn't 'WHERE NOT' with NULL-rows working?

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

*Maybe I'm just missing something. Since the problem is too unspecific to google it / search for it, I am now looking for help here. Tested in **MySQL***

**My Question: Why doesn't this SELECT output [ id=2 ]?**

```sql
SELECT `id` FROM `testtable1` WHERE NOT (`key_boolean` = 1);
```

---

**Table Definition and Test-Data:**

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testtable1` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`key_boolean` tinyint NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

INSERT INTO `testtable1` (`key_boolean`) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO `testtable1` () VALUES ();
```

**In the table is now stored:**

| id | key_boolean |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | *NULL* |

---

**Edit:**
Based on the answers I actually found some more similar questions on StackOverflow. This post fits well for MySQL: [MYSQL syntax not evaluating not equal to in presence of NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186674/mysql-syntax-not-evaluating-not-equal-to-in-presence-of-null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `key_boolean = 1` evaluates to `NULL` when `key_boolean` is `NULL`. So you intermediately have `NOT NULL` for `NOT (key_boolean = 1)`. `NOT NULL`, in turn, also evaluates to `NULL`. And as `NULL` isn't true (yet not false either -- in SQL a [ternary logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic#SQL) applies), the row is not selected.

With the exception of a few, all comparison operations, like `=`, evaluate to `NULL`, if one of their operands is `NULL`. One notable exception in MySQL, in this case, is the [`NULL`-safe equal `<=>`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to), which behaves like you might want it.

You can select the (sub) expressions from your test table and see their results for yourself.

```
SELECT *,
       key_boolean = 1,
       NOT (key_boolean = 1),
       key_boolean <=> 1,
       NOT (key_boolean <=> 1)
       FROM testtable1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=24d6612ff1e5a4ca952736c5b7127cf7)

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I find the answers from @sticky-bit and @ysth very helpful, but I would like to share some more information about my research:

**Conclusion:**
SQL follows the three-value logic (3VL). That means besides TRUE(1) and FALSE(0) there is also NULL. And that means that if one of the operands in a comparison is NULL, the result is also NULL. See also truth table on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#Comparisons_with_NULL_and_the_three-valued_logic_(3VL)

---

*Example 1 without NOT:*

`SELECT id FROM testtable1 WHERE (key_boolean = 1);`, so:

- [row 1] `key_boolean` = 1 --> 1 = 1 --> TRUE
- [row 2] `key_boolean` = 1 --> NULL = 1 --> NULL

**-> so, row 1 is selected.**

*Example 2, just like example 1, only negated, so ​with **NOT**:*

`SELECT id FROM testtable1 WHERE NOT (key_boolean = 1);`, so

- [row 1] NOT (`key_boolean`) = 1 --> 1 = 1 --> TRUE
- [row 2] NOT (`key_boolean`) = 1 --> NULL = 1 --> NULL

**-> empty result.**

---

**Solutions to the problem:**

As @sticky-bit has already written, there is NULL-safe equal in MySQL, which in this example also achieves the desired result.
<=> unfortunately only works in MySQL (and then also in MariaDB). I found a comparison of the different dialects at https://modern-sql.com/feature/is-distinct-from. @ysth's suggestion with "CASE WHEN" probably works in all dialects, but blows up select-terms.

In my specific case (no longer part of the actual question) I have now solved it with a `COALESCE()` - determined a default for NULL values, because in my case, i have to not only support mysql, see:

```sql
SELECT `id` FROM `testtable1` WHERE NOT (COALESCE(`key_boolean`, 0) = 1);
```

**Further reading:**
If, like me, one has never heard of NULL-safe equal operator <=>, see: [What is this operator <=> in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927117/what-is-this-operator-in-mysql/21928508#21928508)

Now I am by no means a database technician, but know NULL as undefined (from other programming languages). The obvious question to me is why at least SQL doesn't use the NULL-safe equal every time. See: [Is there a reason not to use <=> (null safe equals operator) in mysql instead of =?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037298/is-there-a-reason-not-to-use-null-safe-equals-operator-in-mysql-instead-of/10037362#10037362) and [Is there a reason not to use <=> (null safe equals operator) in mysql instead of =?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037298/is-there-a-reason-not-to-use-null-safe-equals-operator-in-mysql-instead-of/16463613#16463613) [*each with a marked post*].

Answer (score 0):

NULL conceptually means indeterminate.  So NOT NULL is also NULL, and false.  You can test `CASE WHEN key_boolean=1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END` if you want to include NULL.

Comment: I see. But why does this (NULL = indeterminate) matter in my specific WHERE?
In this case I first look for `key_boolean`=1 and then negate the result. Basically a WHERE IN WHERE:
"SELECT `id` FROM `testtable1` WHERE `id` NOT IN (SELECT `id` FROM `testtable1` WHERE `key_boolean` = 1);"

Comment: if it's indeterminate, it's not clearly =1, but it's also not clearly !=1.

Comment: Okay, quote "if it's indeterminate, it's not clearly =1" is a good thing at first. 
The Term "SELECT `id` FROM `testtable1` WHERE `key_boolean` = 1;" outputs only [id = 1], too. 

So, why doesn't mysql evalute the inner term "`key_boolean` = 1" first (which outputs [id = 1]) and than negate the result of the inner term? The "also not clearly != 1" should be irrelevant, shouldn't? What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are missing.  if either operand of `=` is NULL, the result is NULL.  so if `key_boolean` is NULL,  `key_boolean = 1` is NULL.  and `NOT( key_boolean = 1 )` is `NOT NULL` which is still NULL.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. Yes, now it makes sense to me.